# Kalman filter: updating the state-transition model

Tags: kalman-filter

I am currently reading lots of material on the Kalman filter (in order to do some experiments), and there is something that I don't get, and I can't get a clear understanding.

I'll stick to the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kalman_filter) notation, $\mathbf{F}_k$ is the state transition model and defines how the state goes from step $k$ to step $k+1$.

As I read it, there is a subscript, which means to me that it can change over time (and that makes sense).

However, the "update" step **does not** describe **how** I get the new estimation of $\mathbf{F}$.

**Example**: Consider a robot moving (more or less) randomly in a 2D space.
At first, say I have a 45° line motion.
If speed is constant, my state is described by
$\left[ x \: y \: vx \: vy \right]$, and I'll have
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
x_{k+1} \\ y_{k+1} \\ vx_{k+1} \\ vy_{k+1}
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & \Delta t & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & \Delta t \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
x_k \\ y_k \\ vx_k \\ vy_k
\end{bmatrix}
$$

But when the robot changes directions, then that state matrix is not valid anymore!

How do I get the updated $\mathbf{F}$ matrix?
What is the point I missed?

**Edit** to clarify: I have some sample working code that is able to provide a good tracking, and it keeps the same state-mode matrix all the way.
But I just don't understand how that can work.

**Edit2**: forgot to mention, but the estimation of the covariance matrix $\mathbf{P}$ at a given step also relies on $\mathbf{F}$:
$$
\mathbf{P} = \mathbf{F} \: \mathbf{P} \: \mathbf{F}^{-1} + \mathbf{Q}
$$
How can that possibly work if the motion (expressed by the state-mode matrix $\mathbf{F}$) is incorrect? I really must have something wrong here...

Comment: The state transition matrix is given exogeneously; it is an input to the Kalman filter. It is not "estimated" or "updated" by the Kalman filter. I don't know anything about robot movement, it may require a different perspective than the one you've described here to use the Kalman filter for that.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. This is a mystery for me: how can the filter provide a good estimate (and it does!) with an incorrect state update model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answers:

1. "which means to me that it can change over time". Yes, the state-space coefficients can indeed depend on time. However, to be more precise, it is the **time interval $\Delta t_k$** the coefficient usually depends on instead of time $t$. For example, if you have uniform $\Delta t_k$ for all $k$'s, then $F$ is independent of $k$.
2. "However, the "update" step does not describe how I get the new estimation of $F$". The Kalman update step **does not** estimate $F$.
3. "But when the robot changes directions, then that state matrix is not valid anymore! How do I get the updated $F$ matrix? What is the point I missed?". The model you are showing is a Wiener velocity model which describes any target motion in terms of position and velocity. When the robot changes its direction, the model is still a **valid** model, simply because you have forgotten the noise term. Denote $z = [x\,y\,v_x\,v_y]$. The complete model is $z_k = F \, z_{k-1} + q_{k-1}$, where $q_{k-1} \sim N(0, Q)$ is a Gaussian r.v. with covariance $Q$ depending only on $\Delta t_k$. This noise term $q$ accounts for the permutation/uncertainty of target's position and velocity. Without $q$, your model target will go along a straight line, and of course the direction will not change. With $q$, your model target will have a random trajectory with direction changes. You can try simulate the trajectory and see.

Think of the dynamic model as a prior on your target. The Kalman filter update step's job is to "correct" the prediction from the prior model by using the likelihood model (i.e., your measurement model) and measurement/data.

4. "How do I get the updated $F$ matrix? What is the point I missed". If you really want to get more precise $F$ (and $Q$), you may parameterise $F$ ($Q$) with some parameters, say, $\theta$, and get $F(\theta)$ (and $Q(\theta)$). Then you can estiamte $\theta$ by performing maximum likelihood estimation.

Comment: Thanks for that detailed answer!

Answer (score 1):

$F_k$ *can* change over time, but doesn't need to. The wikipedia article is suggesting that $F_k$ can change, perhaps as part of your filter's design (i.e. *you* may choose how it evolves in your design). But often, $F_0 = F_1 = ... F_k$.

So you are doing nothing wrong, just you are seeing a generalized syntax.

Comment: Thanks for you answer. As I said in comment above, I don't understand how the filter can provide a good estimate (and it -usually-does) with an incorrect state update model!!

Comment: Why do you think the state matrix isn't valid anymore?

Comment: Well, if the object changes directions (say, 180° turn), then we go from $x_{k+1} = x_k + \Delta t. vx$ to $x_{k+1} = x_k - \Delta t. vx$.

Comment: Arg... I think I am starting to understand were my assumptions are bad... Let me check.

Comment: Please fill us in on your solution - it will help others!